# How to plot two points with matrix?

Tags: python, plot, surface, points

I have to plot two points which as read as below after i print.

i have tried to plot as scatter plot and form lines between them but it was not done.

```
l=0.5,w=0.4,h=0.1
center=(0.1,0.25,0.4)
J= [[array([[1.]]) array([[-0.]]) array([[0.]])]
 [array([[-0.]]) array([[-1.]]) array([[0.]])]
 [array([[0.]]) array([[-0.]]) array([[-1.]])]]

def cuboid(center, size):
    ox, oy, oz = center
    l, w, h = size
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') ##plot the project cuboid
    X=[ox-l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox-l/2]
    Y=[oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2]
    Z=[oz-h/2,oz-h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz-h/2,oz-h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2]
    for i in range(0,8):
        c=np.matrix([[X[i]],
                    [Y[i]],
                    [Z[i]]])
        u=J*c
        print('new_corner=\n',u)
```

You will get the answer like this corner as answer....

```
new_corner=
 [[array([[1.95]])]
 [array([[0.3]])]
 [array([[-0.708]])]]
```

Like this you will get all 8 corners of a cuboid. Now i want to draw the cube using these corners either surface plot or line between corners.

Comment: `center=(o.1,0.25,0.4)` is it letter `o`?

Comment: sorry it was wrong typing mistake. It is '0'. Now i have changed

Comment: Hi @Masoud, Have solved the question?